# Number of rows changes even after `pandas.merge` with `left` option

Tags: python, pandas

I am merging two data frames using `pandas.merge`. Even after specifying `how = left` option, I found the number of rows of merged data frame is larger than the original. Why does this happen?

```
panel = pd.read_csv(file1, encoding ='cp932')
before_len = len(panel)

prof_2000 = pd.read_csv(file2, encoding ='cp932').drop_duplicates()

temp_2000 = pd.merge(panel, prof_2000, left_on='Candidate_u', right_on="name2", how="left")

after_len =  len(temp_2000)
print(before_len, after_len)
> 12661 13915
```

Comment: You can get an unexpected number of rows if you merge on keys having Nans.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This sounds like having more than one rows in `right` under `'name2'` that match the key you have set for the `left`. Using option `'how='left'` with [`pandas.DataFrame.merge()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) only means that:

> - left: use only keys from left frame

However, the actual number of rows in the result object is not necessarily going to be the same as the number of rows in the `left` object.

Example:

```
In [359]: df_1
Out[359]: 
   A    B
0  a  AAA
1  b  BBA
2  c  CCF
```

and then another DF that looks like this (notice that there are more than one entry for your desired key on the left):

```
In [360]: df_3
Out[360]: 
  key  value
0   a      1
1   a      2
2   b      3
3   a      4
```

If I merge these two on `left.A`, here's what happens:

```
In [361]: df_1.merge(df_3, how='left', left_on='A', right_on='key')
Out[361]: 
   A    B  key  value
0  a  AAA    a    1.0
1  a  AAA    a    2.0
2  a  AAA    a    4.0
3  b  BBA    b    3.0
4  c  CCF  NaN    NaN
```

This happened even though I merged with `how='left'` as you can see above, there were simply more than one rows to merge and as shown here the result `pd.DataFrame` has in fact more rows than the `pd.DataFrame` on the `left`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer is perfect! Thanks! In my case, `.drop_duplicates(subset="name2")` drops duplicate rows and it was fine for my purpose!

Comment: Glad that helped, best of luck!

Answer (score 8):

The problem of doubling of rows after each `merge()` (of any type, 'both' or 'left') is usually caused by duplicates in any of the keys, so we need to drop them first:

```
left_df.drop_duplicates(subset=left_key, inplace=True)
right_df.drop_duplicates(subset=right_key, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have any duplication, as indicated in the above answer. You should double-check the names of removed entries. In my case, I discovered that the names of removed entries are inconsistent between the `df1` and `df2` and I solved the problem by:

```
df1["col1"] = df2["col2"]
```